# Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 43 Windows 7 R studio

Tags: r, pdf, rstudio, knitr

I have search the answers in the forum, but they dont seem to work.

I am knitting a pdf document in Rstudio using the knitr package. I am using Windows 7 and Rstudio.

```
pandoc.exe: Error producing PDF from TeX source
Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 43
In addition: Warning message:
running command '"C:/Program Files/RStudio/bin/pandoc/pandoc" PA1_template.utf8.md --to latex --from markdown+autolink_bare_uris+ascii_identifiers+tex_math_single_backslash-implicit_figures --output PA1_template.pdf --template "C:\R\Library\rmarkdown\rmd\latex\default.tex" --highlight-style tango --latex-engine pdflatex --variable "geometry:margin=1in"' had status 43 
Execution halted
```

Thanks,

Luis

Comment: Hi, the issue was resolved. see https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/issues/313#issuecomment-63334513

Comment: This is still broken for me, including when I try and knit to pdf a simple Rmd including only the `output: pdf_document` header (with three hyphens on the preceding and subsequent line) and, on a new line, the word `test`.

Comment: Same problem here on Mac OS X Mavericks and rmarkdown 0.5.1

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue but on Linux using the latest rmarkdown package and pandoc 1.13. In essence it seems like pdflatex does not work with the output generated by pandoc - you need to replace the latex-engine pdflatex with xelatex (part of TeXLive)

For rmarkdown my solution was to edit the file

```
rmarkdown/templates/tufte_handout/resources/tufte-common.def
```

and replace the line

```
\typeoutbool{pdfatex}{@tufte@pdf}
```

with

```
\typeoutbool{xelatex}{@tufte@pdf}
```

Then xelatex will be used instead of pdflatex to generate pdf's with rmarkdown

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue, here are the steps I took to solve the problem:

- install devtools in Rstudio (`install.packages(devtools)`)
- install rmarkdown (`devtools::install_github("rstudio/rmarkdown")`)
- fix the files tufte-common.def and tufte-handout.tex in `~/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2/rmarkdown/rmarkdown/templates/tufte_handout/resources/`

If the rmarkdown installation did not go smoothly this way then do it like this (`devtools::install_github("git://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown")`)

In tufte-common.def do the following:

- Add this line
  `\typeoutbool{xelatex}{@tufte@pdf}`
- uncomment this line
  `\typeoutbool{xelatex}{@tufte@xetex}` remember % is used to uncomment latex

Add the following lines in tufte-handout.tex:

`% UTF encoding 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`

When I tried to compile a document I still got the following error  `(! Font \XeTeXLink@font=pzdr at 0.00002pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file or ins talled font not found.)`, I tackled it by installing `texlive-fonts-recommended`:

`sudo apt-get install texlive-fonts-recommended`

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. Telling knitr where to find the pdf-engine was necessary even though I had it on the windows path. Here is the header of the knitr.Rmd-document, that solved the problem for me:

```
---
title: "XXX"
author: "XXX"
date: '2016-11-28'
output:
  pdf_document:
    keep_tex: yes
    pandoc_args:
    - --latex-engine
    - C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/miktex/bin/x64/pdflatex.exe
    toc: yes
---
```