# Error producing PDF from TeX source Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 43 Execution halted

Tags: r, rstudio, knitr, r-markdown

I am new to R and have been trying to write my project report in R markdown. However I am facing issues. I tried implementing solutions present on stack overflow as well as other websites, but I have not been able to make progress.

Details:

R version 3.2.1 (2015-06-18) -- "World-Famous Astronaut"

RStudio Version 0.99.441 – © 2009-2015

Mac OS X Yosemite version 10.10.5

Installed pandoc 1.15.0.6 
https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/releases/tag/1.15.0.6

The MacTeX-2015 Distribution from http://tug.org/mactex/

mactex-20150613

Under Global options I have weave Rnw files using knitr, Typeset LaTeX into PDF using XeLaTex, have deselected clean auxiliary output after compile.

I get the following error:

output file: 07.Random_Forest.knit.md

/usr/local/bin/pandoc 07.Random_Forest.utf8.md --to latex --from markdown+autolink_bare_uris+ascii_identifiers+tex_math_single_backslash-implicit_figures --output 07.Random_Forest.pdf --template /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.2/Resources/library/rmarkdown/rmd/latex/default-1.14.tex --highlight-style tango --latex-engine /Library/TeX/texbin/pdflatex 
! Undefined control sequence.
l.921 {\centering \includegraphics

pandoc: Error producing PDF from TeX source
Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 43
Execution halted

Part of my R markdown code is attached for reference:

````
---
title: "Decision Trees and Random Forest"

paper: a4paper
fontsize: 12pt
geometry: 
  - tmargin=2cm
  - bmargin=2cm
  - lmargin=3cm
  - rmargin=3cm
documentclass: report
classoption: twoside, bindingoffset=1cm
linkcolor: blue

author: "Chaitanya Jagtap"
date: "15 September 2015"
output: pdf_document


---

opts_chunk$set(echo=FALSE, warning=FALSE, message=FALSE, error=FALSE, collapse=TRUE,     tidy=TRUE, highlight=TRUE, comment='')

opts_knit$set(progress=TRUE, verbose=TRUE)




```{r include=TRUE} 

library(extrafont)
loadfonts()

library(SDMTools)
library(caTools)
library(randomForest)
library(rpart)
library(rattle)
library(rpart.plot)
library(RColorBrewer)
library(partykit)

library(rmarkdown)
library(geometry)
library(knitr)
library(highr)
library(xtable)


set.seed(211)

fonttable()

options(digits=4)
par(cex=0.9,cex.axis=1,cex.lab=1,cex.main=1.2,cex.sub=1,
    font=1,font.axis=1,font.lab=2,font.main=2,font.sub=1, 
    pin=c(4,3), mai=c(1, 1, 1, .2), oma=c(0.2,0.2,2,0.2), mgp = c(3, 1, 0),          adj=0.5,
    las=0, xaxs="i", yaxs="i",
    col.lab = "firebrick4", col.main="deepskyblue4", col.sub="royalblue",     lab=c(10,10,7),
    lwd=2,family="Times New Roman", ps=12)


setwd("/Users/Urmila/Desktop/Chaitanya/Study/001_Great     Lakes/001_Capstone/002_Give_me_some_credit/")

load("capstone_df_train.RData") 
load("capstone_df_test.RData") 

xyvar <- c( "GB", "Age_woe",  "num_30_59_dpd_woe",   "num_60_89_dpd_woe",      "num_90_dpd_woe",
            "num_open_trades_woe",  "num_RE_trades_woe",   "Rev_Util_unsec_woe",     "Debt_Ratio_woe",
            "MI_num_depend_woe") 

xvar <- c("Age_woe",  "num_30_59_dpd_woe",   "num_60_89_dpd_woe",  "num_90_dpd_woe",
            "num_open_trades_woe",  "num_RE_trades_woe",   "Rev_Util_unsec_woe",     "Debt_Ratio_woe",
            "MI_num_depend_woe") 

capstone_df_train_xyvar <- capstone_df_train[xyvar]
capstone_df_test_xyvar <- capstone_df_test[xyvar]


weight <- ifelse(capstone_df_train_xyvar$GB == 0,1,12)

dtree_train <- rpart(GB ~ ., data=capstone_df_train_xyvar,
                     method="class", parms=list(split="information"), 
                     minsplit = 1000, minbucket = 500, cp=-1, 
                     weights = weight)
```

```{r  include = TRUE} 

dtree_train$cptable

```



```{r  include=TRUE, fig.align='center', fig.cap="Plot of cross-validated error     against complexity parameter cp"} 

plotcp(dtree_train, minline = TRUE, lty=2, col = "firebrick", upper = "size")
mtext("Plot of cross-validated error against complexity parameter cp",         side=3,     cex=1.1,
line=0.6, col = "dodgerblue4",   outer=TRUE)
box("plot", col="blue", lty = "solid")
box("figure", col="forestgreen", lty = "solid")

```
````

Thank you for your time and help.

Chaitanya

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26974670/error-pandoc-document-conversion-failed-with-error-43-windows-7-r-studio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pandoc does not know your output contains graphics, because you used the chunk option `fig.align = 'center'`. You can add `graphics: yes` to the YAML metadata of your R Markdown document.

Comment: Thank you Yihui, I am able to get the pdf output now.