# R Markdown, can not convert to pdf (error 43)

Tags: r, pdf, r-markdown

I have a trouble making a pdf file in R Markdown, the error says "pandoc.exe: Error producing PDF
ERROR: pandoc document conversion failed with error 43", I tried everything I found, updating MiKTeX, changing pdfLatex to Telatex, updating packages, nothing worked and I keep having that error over and over, however it is occuring only when I try to add plot to my pdf presentation, because without plots and with just text it is working fine. If you know what may be a cause of that error I would be very thankful, if it won't work I will try to reinstall R later

Comment: Please include a minimal example that reproduces your problem. You might also try http://stackoverflow.com/a/32596848/6455166.

Comment: http://imgur.com/DDQEaRL this is how my window looks like, without that line plot(w1), where w1 is a vector i defined before everything is fine, but when I try to add plot or boxplot or something that is connected to graphic,  that error occurs

Comment: I think that I am missing something, like a package but I installed like everything I found in another topics and it didn't help

Comment: did you check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25856362/pandoc-document-conversion-failed-with-error-43-pdflatex-the-memory-dump-file

Comment: When I try to use devtools::install_github("rstudio/rmarkdown") I get an error 'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Error: Command failed (1)

Comment: I did something I found on another topic: 
I FIGURED IT OUT. Whatever installer RStudio is using for this aborts command when it encounters a space in a file directory. My system drive is structured C:/Program Files/etc. When I re-installed R and RStudio into C:/R_Program_Files/, everything started working fine., and everything is working, thanks for help